# What Chemistry Sets come with the "Collector's" quality?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Just came out today, but nothing in the schemas point to what chem sets would have the "Collector's" quality.

What chem sets come with the "Collector's" quality?

Comment: I've seen an ullapool caber, but that's it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a large selection of known collector's quality items.

This is currently a new feature and new information is likely to come up often, The wiki below seems to be the most up to date source of information:

http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Collector%27s

Answer (score 0):

I do believe its only the Ullapool Caber at the moment. Not sure though.

Source:http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Collector%27s